# OBIEE YTD Issues

Tags: oracle12c, obiee

I have a fact table housing different granularity (date grain)

1. Monthly
2. Daily

The month data can be accessed by filtering by end of month date or using YYYYMM date format. In OBIEE RPD repo, the fact is set to LAST Aggregation.

I want to perform Year to Date analysis. And I want to sum only month end dates.

Using function TODATE(Measure), it tends to sum up all the data through out the month e.grain

```
Date            Amount  YTD TODate(Amount)
31/01/2106      100     100
28/02/2016      200     300
14/03/2016      50      350*
31/03/2016      100     450
```

I want YTD to ignore 50 and return 400, so also any other dates that falls within any month. And if if I Select 14/03/2016 I want 350 to return.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit the base table / RPD? There is some LTS work you should do that would do this for you / speed up performance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I can edit base table and RPD... Please help identify the LTS work.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alter the table to add a flag, something that flags `Y` if the record is at the specified monthly grain, and `N` if the record is not at the specified monthly grain.

In the logical layer, create two distinct `LTSs` with the first filtering on the flag for `Y`. This will be where you will calculate and source all your to date measures. The second LTS can either be filtered to `N`, or can be left to all the data depending on what you want to do with it.

The performance increases should come from the fact that any month measures you build off that monthly `LTS` will only hit records flagged as month, and will bypass all that other data that is not relevant. So if a user runs a report only asking for monthly measures, the query will automatically filter to that specific data.

What will happen is if a user selects your  to date measure and a specific date measure on the same report, OBIEE should fire off two separate queries to get the data and stitch together based on common dimensions.

Could someone create this in the front end? Probably. You would have to do some sort of `PERIODROLLING` function, and tell it to aggregate at the month level, but I am afraid it may still roll those days up into a larger than desired number. A `TODATE` function will not work here.